# Assigning histogram bin to each data point

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

I have an array `days=[1,4,5,2,7,2,7,8,3,10]`.I created a histogram from this array by using `a,b=numpy.histogram(days,bins=5)`. value of a and b comes out to be

```
a=[3,2,1,3,1]
b=[1., 2.8, 4.6, 6.4, 8.2, 10.]
```

what i want is to create another array label same size as `days` but it should tell me which bin data in `days` belong to. In this case output should be

```
label=[1,2,3,1,4,1,4,4,2,5]
```

here it means that there are 5 bins in all. days[0]=1 belongs to label[0]=1st bin days[1]=4 belongs to label[1]=2nd bin and so on. I can use for loop and iterate over each element of days compare them with bin interval but I have large data set say days will have close to 4000 points and there will be 20 bins. So if I iterate over all data and make comparison to each bin there would be 20 comparison making code cluttered. Is there a way to reduce this clutter and automate the entire procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) can generate the labels:

```
In [68]: a, b = np.histogram(days,bins=5)

In [69]: np.digitize(days, bins=b)
Out[69]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 6])
```

Note that you don't need to call `np.histogram` first; that was only to make `np.digitize` use the same bins as those generated by `np.histogram`. You could also generate the bins with:

```
In [71]: np.linspace(1, 10, 6)
Out[71]: array([  1. ,   2.8,   4.6,   6.4,   8.2,  10. ])
```

or, more generally,

```
In [76]: np.linspace(min(days), max(days), 6)
Out[76]: array([  1. ,   2.8,   4.6,   6.4,   8.2,  10. ])
```

---

By default, `np.digitize` uses half-open intervals with the right bin edge not included. If `right=True` then the right bin edge is included, but the left is not:

```
In [72]: np.digitize(days, bins=b, right=True)
Out[72]: array([0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5])
```

To get the exact output you posted, you could extend the right-most bin edge a little bit:

```
In [80]: np.digitize(days, bins=np.linspace(1, np.nextafter(10,np.inf), 6))
Out[80]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5])
```

Although `bins=np.linspace(1, 11, 6)` also works for this example, it is better to increment 10 by the smallest amount possible so that the other bin edges are changed as little as possible.
`np.nextafter(10, np.inf)` returns the next number representable as a float after 10 in the direction of `np.inf`.

```
In [82]: np.nextafter(10,np.inf)
Out[82]: 10.000000000000002
```